# json.net handling tokens that don't exist

Tags: c#, json.net

What is the best way to detect if a token exists? I am using the crude way of simply catching the error if it happens but there must be a way to detect if it exists:

```
try { Response.Write(token["key"]); }
catch { }
```

I have tried something like this:

```
if (token["disambiguated"].FirstOrDefault().HasValues)
```

but that does not seem to work.

Thanks,
Steve.

Answer (score 7):

```
token["disambiguated"] == null
```

to check that token exists

```
token["disambiguated"].HasValues
```

to check that token has values

Answer (score 0):

How are you populating the token?  If `token` is an instantiated (not null) value, then `token["key"]` should simply return null, not throw an exception. It obviously would throw a null exception if `token` is null so all you should need to do is make sure `token` is not null.  I just tested this on the latest version of json.net.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create a method you can pass the token into that will validate whether to object/property/element exists. You will need to have the NuGet package Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to perform this action.

Method:

```
    public static bool TokenIsNullOrEmpty(JToken token)
    {
        return (token == null) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Array && !token.HasValues) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Object && !token.HasValues) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.String && token.ToString() == String.Empty) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Null);
    }
```

Then you can use a conditional to provide a value whether  an element/object/property exists:

var variable = TokenIsNullOrEmpty(obj["object/element/property name"]) == false ? obj["object/element/property name"].ToString() : "";

Hope this was helpful. Regards.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not intimate with JSON.NET for deserialising JSON, but if you're using C# 4 then you can get quite a simple solution via dynamic code.

I posted [some code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-dynamic-object/3806407#3806407) that would allow you to write the code above like this:

```
if (token.key!=null)
    Response.Write(token.key);
```

If you're only using JSON.NET for deserialising JSON then this may be a simpler solution for you.